# Can I Pass a return value of a getter method to a setter method of another object in a different class?

Tags: java

```
customer1.setExcursion1() = cust_dest.get_excursion1();
```

`customer1` and `cust_dest` are two different objects from two different classes.

Can I pass the return value of

```
cust_dest.get_excursion1();
```

to the

`my customer1.setExcursion1()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can - but not like that. You call the setter method, passing in the value as an argument - you're currently trying to assign a value to the method call, which makes no sense.

You want:

```
customer1.setExcursion1(cust_dest.get_excursion1());
```

(Your naming is inconsistent, by the way. It should be `getExcursion1`, at least - and ideally just `getExcursion`. What is the `1` meant to be for? Likewise `cust_dest` should be `custDest` if you're not changing the words - or ideally something rather more descriptive.)